# Codeigniter style validation callback function not working

Tags: add-on-development, validation

I've created an EE custom addon that processes a simple enquiry form. All works well but I'm trying to add a callback function to my validation rules and it appears to be completely ignored.

Here's my call to the validation rule:

```
ee()->form_validation->set_rules('url', 'URL', 'callback_honeypot'); // Honeypot field
```

and my callback function (which is in the same file) is:

```
public function honeypot($input)
{
    if (!empty($input))
    {
        ee()->form_validation->set_message('honeypot', '<p>Not all is as it should be...</p>');
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Will the standard CI form validation callback method not work with EE?

**Update / workaround:**

Although I haven't got the callback method to work, a simple workaround for (in my case) a honeypot field is to hide the field on the frontend form and use something like this:

```
ee()->form_validation->set_rules('nickname', 'Nickname', 'max_length[1]');
```

So if the 'nickname' field has more than one character entered into it, the validation fails.

Alternatively, you could do this:

`$honeypot_field = ee()->input->post('nickname', TRUE);`

and only process the form if the following conditions are met:

`if (ee()->form_validation->run() == TRUE && (empty($honeypot_field)))`

But it doesn't answer the question of why the proper CI callback functionality doesn't work in EE.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is check that your conditional is running as expected.

```
if (!empty($input))
{
echo "I have Input"
exit();
}else{
echo "I have no Input"
exit();
}
```

Also, not all CodeIgniter functions are available in EE's branch, though this one seems to be there.